# Find matching elements on the same index in a list of lists?

Tags: python

I am coding a tic tac toe game the game board looks as follows:

```
game = [[1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 0],]
```

I am trying the following function:

```
def vertical_win(game):
    for column, row in enumerate(game):
        check = []
        check.append(row[0])
        if check.count(check[0]) == len(check) and check[0] != 0:
            print("Winner")
```

Output:

```
Winner
Winner
Winner
```

it is only iterating over the 0th element of each list. And if the number it displays winner for a each number per row instead of matching all three numbers of each list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write the following:

```
def vertical_win(game):
    # looping over all the items in the first item of the game
    for column in range(len(game[0])):
        # going over all the other games, and checking if they have the same values in a certain column
        for other in range(1, len(game)):
            # if they don't have the same value in a column break, since it won't be necessary to check
            # if all the items in game have the same value in a specific column, that
            # means that there will be no breaks so the else statement will run
            if game[0][column] != game[other][column]:
                break
        else:
            # return True if didn't break out of loop
            return True
    # return False if we didn't return True at any time
    return False
```

The function returns true when there is a vertical win, and it is also completely dynamic to the size of the game, so it could even work on a 4x4 grid. Also, if you want to, you can know in which index the win occurs by returning `column` together with the already returned value when returning True.

Comment: This was really helpful. I just have one question, the loop is checking each column for a match, but i noticed that whenever there is a column filled with zeroes it does not return true, but if there are three zeroes in a column it should return true since there is a match. How come the function handle this case?

Comment: It works for me. For ```game = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0]]```, It outputs ```True```.

Comment: yes it works for me as well, I was just wondering why it does not return true whenever there is a column with three 0's

Comment: Yes, it does return True for such a column. I tried running it on my computer, with exactly the function in the answer (and game with the values detailed before), and it returns ```True```

Comment: Perhaps you could send the code you're trying to run and I'll take a look?

Comment: What is the point of detecting a winner without being able to determine *who* won?

Comment: I'm still working on it. I'm first getting down the functions to determine how a player is able to win, then I will add players 1 and 2, then a function to update the board each time a player makes a move, and finally a function to determine when a player has won.

Comment: @blorgon you could just say that ```game[0][column]``` won. You could also return that from the function, but I just did it as the original poster did in his question, in which he only printed out ```"Winner"```

Comment: Sure, but it's horrendously convoluted to return `game[0][column]`. It takes an unnecessary amount of effort to understand what any of this code is doing without the aid of excessive in-line comments.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to get the "columns" of the game board is to use `zip()`:

```py
>>> cols = [*zip(*game)]
>>> cols
[(1, 1, 1), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0)]
```

From here you can check for a win with a membership test:

```py
if (0, 0, 0) in cols:
    print("player 0 wins")
elif (1, 1, 1) in cols:
    print("player 1 wins")
```

Putting it together:

```py
def vertical_win(game):
    cols = [*zip(*game)]
    if (0, 0, 0) in cols:
        print("player 0 wins")
    elif (1, 1, 1) in cols:
        print("player 1 wins")
```

You can very easily extend this to larger board sizes with this small modification:

```py
def vertical_win(game):
    n = len(game)
    cols = [*zip(*game)]
    if (0,)*n in cols:
        print("player 0 wins")
    elif (1,)*n in cols:
        print("player 1 wins")
```

As for why your code isn't working:

```py
>>> def vertical_win(game):
...     for col, row in enumerate(game):
...             print(col, row)
...             check = []
...             check.append(row[0])
...             print(check)
...
>>>
>>> vertical_win(game)
0 [1, 0, 1]
[1]
1 [1, 1, 0]
[1]
2 [1, 1, 0]
[1]
```

For all three iterations, the boolean expression `if check.count(check[0]) == len(check) and check[0] != 0` for this particular board state is always going to be true because `check[0] == 1` and `check.count(1) == len([1])` and `check[0] == 1` which is `!= 0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def vertical_win(game):
    for column in range(3):
        score = sum(row[column] for row in game)
        if score == 0 or score == 3:
            print("Winner")
```